# What should be the max amount of data stored in an Android app's internal storage space?

Tags: android, storage

Android provide [2 main options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) when you need to store a fair amount of files within an app:

- Internal storage
- External storage

I need to store from 5 MB up to 100MB of data (XML, images, HTML, sounds) and I'm trying to decide what option should be the default.

In an ideal world, internal storage sounds like the best option:

- it adds some control access
- it's available 100% of the time [EDIT: my app should be fully functional offline]
- ... but it can also be very limited

On the other hand, external storage would be larger, but may not be available 100% of the time.

What are your thoughts about this issue. What should be the max. amount of data an app can store on a device's internal storage space without ruining the whole Android experience for the user?

Comment: Why don't you store data on server get only the relevant part from the server when required.

Comment: My app should be fully functional offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that the question is about where to [install the application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html). It's a trade off between saving the user's internal storage and providing full time access.

From my point of view, as soon as you app weights more than 20 MB, you should make it install on the external storage. If the external storage becomes unavailable, I probably means that the user is not using any app...

On top of that, lots of heavy apps get bad ratings for not allowing installation on external storage (Chrome is an famous example weighing more than 60 MB).

Comment: Sounds like a good compromise! Thanks!

Comment: All the app private data like databases will still be stored into the internal storage. Plus, you can not share the app installed into one device with another device with the same SD card.

Only .apk will be stored into the external storage. System will also kill your application when you enable USB storage share for your device and even you can experience undefined errors during this progress.

So what's the point of using external storage for apk installation?